# Google Tasks doesnt set Time. Only date

Tags: google-apps-script

this is my code. evething is fine except the time set for the task. I mean the script registers a task with the date intended, but not the time. the task is posted as all-day task.
Please Help.

```
function addTask() {
  var taskListId = "something";
  var task = {
  title: 'Hello World With Date',
  notes: 'Hello World Remember...',
  due: "2021-03-23T18:46:00+0600"
};
task = Tasks.Tasks.insert(task, taskListId);
Logger.log('Task with ID "%s" was created.', task.id);
```

}

Comment: You can vote on Google's public issue tracker to make this data accessible via the API. The issue is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128979662

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior. [Task Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tasks) in Apps Script uses [Google Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/tasks).

The request body of your [Tasks.Tasks.insert(resource: Tasks_v1.Tasks.V1.Schema.Task, tasklist: string)](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks/insert) expects an instance of a [Task](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks#Task).

Based on the `due` field:

> **due**
>
> Due date of the task (as a RFC 3339 timestamp). Optional. **The due date only records date information**; the **time portion of the timestamp is discarded** when setting the due date. It isn't possible to read or write the time that a task is due via the API.